# int k = k; How and why does this statement work?

Tags: c, syntax, scope

I think this question is **not a duplicate** of other questions on the site, because others don't give uses of this *feature* in C.

I am interested in knowing why this C program is not giving a compile time error. Also why is this statement valid. What are its uses?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int k = k;
    return 0;
}
```

There is no `k` in the global scope. It looks as if scope of `k` started just after the assignment operator. I am confused.

Comment: Indeed, the scope of a declared name begins right after the end of declarator, that's at the `=` sign in your case. Even if there were a global `i`, that `i` would have been hidden by the newly-declared `i`. You can make some fishy but legal code, e. g.: `int f(int* p), i = f(&i);`

Comment: In the world of programming, "it works/seem to work/once worked" is a very subtle statement.

Comment: RE: your edit—there *are* no uses, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @CodyGray Why not remove it it a language revision if it is undefined in all cases?

Comment: That is not how the C language works. It does not protect you from shooting yourself in the foot. How would it even be "removed"? It is not allowed now!

Answer (score 3):

the `int i = i;` definition initializes the (left) `i`  with the (uninitialized value of the right) `i` (the *same* variable).

It is certainly unspecified behavior, and probably is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The implementation is certainly not expected to always detect undefined behavior (always detecting them reliably can be proved equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)).

But you really should be very [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of undefined behavior. It is your duty to avoid it.

Comment: this is undefined behaviour for sure